# wxPython How are the different sizes used in a wx.Window

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

1. Is there a document as to how these sizes are used in wxPython?
2. What state must the window be in for these sizes to be valid? Hidden, maximized, minimized etc...

   GetBestSize()

   GetEffectiveMinSize()

   GetMaxSize()

   GetMinSize()

   GetSize()

I find this very tricky as there are many size methods and I am not sure how they are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best and most up to date documentation is the one for the wxPython Phoenix project.

http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Window.html?highlight=getsize#Window.GetBestSize

Most of that documentation also applies to the wxPython Classic version, especially if you use wxPython 2.9 or newer.

Note that all overloaded methods have different names in the Classic version where as in Phoenix there is just one name - most of this and more is documented here: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/classic_vs_phoenix.html

The wiki might also be helpful, in particular: wiki.wxpython.org/WindowSizeInfo

With regards to 2., as soon as the window/control is created you will get a value.  Is that valid?  Yes, but if you use sizers and if the layout is not yet updated you might get default values (0, 0) or (20, 20).

If you use sizers to control your layout you should never or very very rarely care about the size of a control.

Comment: well I have an arbitrary number of wx.Panels belonging to a frame which are all hidden (apart from frame) and I want the largest "Size" of them so that the panels do not jump around when they are hidden/shown. Seems like GetBestSize() would be most appropriate

Comment: @Har, I think so too that GetBestSize would be it.

Answer (score 1):

These methods are all individually documented in the [manual](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html). This doesn't answer your question of how exactly are they used internally, but why do you need to know this? After all, you want to use them from outside wxPython, not from inside it.

My short guideline: if you need the size of the window, use `GetSize()`. If you want to get the most appropriate size for the window, i.e. such that it will have just enough size for its contents, and you don't use sizers which ensure this automatically, for some reason, then use `GetBestSize()`. You shouldn't need to call the other methods at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little outdated but there is some info about the various size methods and related things at http://wiki.wxpython.org/WindowSizeInfo